# How to terminate a loop that is reading an input?

Tags: java

I'm wondering how terminate a loop when the end of input is reached. I searched a lot for this but the only solutions I encounter envolve using Scanner which I'm not using. Instead, I am using the following function that reads each line of the input however I'm not quite understanding how can I end a loop that is constantly reading random numbers which means I can't simply put a clause on the while(clause) to reach the end of the loop.

CODE:

The loop that i'm talking about:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "";

    while (true){
        str = readLn(200);
    }
}
```

The method using for read lines:

```
static String readLn (int maxLg){ //utility function to read from stdin
    byte lin[] = new byte [maxLg]; int lg = 0, car = -1;
    String line = "";
    try {
        while (lg < maxLg){
            car = System.in.read();
            if ((car < 0) || (car == '\n')) break; lin [lg++] += car;
        } }
    catch (IOException e){
        return (null);
    }
    if ((car < 0) && (lg == 0)) return (null); // eof
    return (new String (lin, 0, lg));
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you avoid using the Scanner class? Just asking, because you're literally just trying to reproduce logic which already exists.

Comment: Yeah, this is for a college work and we're supposed to submit the solution in an online platform and with that the teacher gave us this specific method to use with Java solutions since the platform performs the stdin that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a stream is closed, the `.read()` call will return -1, which causes `car` to be less than 0, which causes the method to return; `null` if nothing is read yet, otherwise a string with the contents you got so far.

Even if you loop this method, it'll just keep returning `null` - once a stream starts returning -1 it will continue to do so.

Most likely, the stream is *NOT*, in fact, 'closed'. System.in doesn't close just because you wish it so, or because you stop typing. Maybe you'll type some more.

One easy way to 'close' system.in is to pipe a file into your process. something like:

```
echo "hello" | java YourApp
```

if you insist on keyboard input, you're looking at CTRL+Z or CTRL+D depending on OS in order to get standard in to be considered 'closed', and a little praying.

the `while` loop in your main should either `break` if `str` is null, or needs to be a do/while construct, which whiles as long as `str != null`, or just `while` on `str != null`, but then make sure to initialize `str` to a nonnull value or it won't even enter the while in the first place.

The while loop in your readLn method is already causing that loop to end if standard in is closed.

Answer (score 0):

For your special case (there are more efficient ways to read a string from the stdin), the return value in `readLn` is either a string or null for eof.
So you can terminate the loop if the returned value is null:

```
while (true){
    str = readLn(200);
    if (str == null) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I kind of already tried that null trick, even has a clause in the while but it seems not to work. I guess the string retains the last value read so it never become "null".

Comment: @Jesus Your issue is probably that `stdin` - the standard input you are reading from, does not give "end of file" on its own. You need to press Ctrl + D on Linux / Mac OS or Ctrl + Z on Windows to get EOF (-1). To end on an empty line, change your `readLn` function to return `null` if the only character on line is `\n`

Comment: I though about doing that but this method is supposed to be used as it was given with to me by the teacher.

Comment: Are you sure you got this method right? For example `String line = "";` is not used within the method